# Is delta wing design on a fighter a compromise?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, fighter

I apologize for not providing a reference, but I recall reading a Russian designer, I think he had something to do with Mig-29, while talking about Mirage 2000, said that a delta wing is essentially a compromise. He mentioned some technical challenge faced by the designers and if they cannot overcome they fall for a delta. It overcomes something but leaves something else to be desired.

Can somebody please shed some light on it? I am just an enthusiast.

One thing is for sure, no US fighter is a delta.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that any design feature on an aircraft is a compromise.

Comment: @PeterSchilling: Any engineering decision is a compromise, especially when you include money in the equation.